# Remove \n in a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary looks like :

```
{'values_changed': {'root': {'new_value': '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', 'old_value': '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qxxx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', 'diff': '--- \n+++ \n@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n- "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n+ "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n- "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n+ "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n- "qxxx2": {\n+ "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",'}}}
```

I need to remove \n from it; and I tried strip() is not working on it.

How can I remove \n from dictionary so that my dictionary looks like below.

```
{'values_changed': {'root': {'new_value': '{ "quiz": {"sport": {  "q1": {  "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",  "options":[  "New York Bulls",  "Los Angeles Kings",  "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",  "Huston Rocket"  ],  "answer": "Huston Rocket"  }  },  "maths": {  "q1": {  "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",  "options": [  "10",  "11",  "12",  "13"  ],  "answer": "12"  },  "qx0000xx2": {  "question": "12 - 8 = ?",  "options": [  "1",  "2",  "3",  "4"  ],  "answer": "4"  }  }  } }', 'old_value': '{  "quiz": {  "sport": {  "q1": {  "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",  "options": [  "New York Bulls",  "Los Angeles Kings",  "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",  "Huston Rocket"  ], "answer": "Huston Rocket"  }  },  "maths": {  "q1": {  "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",  "options": [  "10",  "11",  "12",  "13"  ],  "answer": "12"  },  "qxxx2": {  "question": "12 - 8 = ?",  "options": [  "1",  "2",  "3",  "4"  ],  "answer": "4"  }  }  } }', 'diff': '---  +++  @@ -6,7+6,7 @@  "options": [  "New York Bulls",  "Los Angeles Kings", - "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros", + "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",  "Huston Rocket"  ], "answer": "Huston Rocket" @@ -14,7 +14,7 @@  },  "maths": {  "q1": { - "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?", + "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",  "options":[  "10",  "11", @@ -23,7 +23,7 @@  ],  "answer": "12"  }, - "qxxx2": { + "qx0000xx2": {  "question": "12 - 8 = ?",  "options": [  "1",'}}}
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have nested newlines. You appear to have a string in JSON format that you can *decode* into a `dict`.

Comment: Could you change your example to the minimal amount of code that replicates your issue?

Comment: Can you confirm what @chepner asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use recursion to replace all nested string values, for example:

```
def remove_n(d):
    for k in d.keys():
        if type(d[k]) == str:
            d[k] = d[k].replace('\n', '')
        elif type(d[k]) == dict:
            remove_n(d[k])

d={'values_changed': {'root': {'new_value': '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', 'old_value': '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qxxx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', 'diff': '--- \n+++ \n@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n- "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n+ "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n- "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n+ "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n- "qxxx2": {\n+ "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",'}}}

remove_n(d)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
d = {'values_changed': {'root': {'new_value': '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', 'old_value': '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qxxx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', 'diff': '--- \n+++ \n@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n- "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n+ "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n- "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n+ "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n- "qxxx2": {\n+ "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",'}}}
```

The value is a string, if you wish to convert it into a dict/json u can:

```
d["values_changed"]["root"]["new_value"] = simplejson.loads(d["values_changed"]["root"]["new_value"])
```

you can do similarily for `old_value`